# Can not use HIDImports from Wiimotelib.dll

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, hid

I am making a app that will use 2 Wii remotes as input . I have the Wiimontelib from Brian Peek and imported the reference in my project . Afte reading his guide several times I started to implement the library , but I ran into a dead end . When calling the classes inside the `dll` , Visual studio does not find any `reference` to them . For example for "`HIDImports.HidD_GetHidGuid`" Visual studio says it can not find any reference to it . In the `dll` the method is devined as a `public external static` I believe.

In other segments I am told that `HIDImports` is not accesible because of it's protection level .

Hope someone can clarify this for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I could not acces the methods in HIDImport was because I was not calling them in the constructor of the class that needed acces to them . Movin the code in the constructor has solved the problem .